# What does this Android code do?

Tags: android

Please explain the given code , what does it means and how it works. 
Here `DictionaryDatabase` is class name in which DataBase Name and Version is defined.

```
public DbObject(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new DictionaryDatabase(context);
    this.db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DictionaryDatabase` is your class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` (your database)
now you want to open your database and (read) or (insert, update, delete) from it to this, you have two options

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();//used for insert, update, delete operations
```

or

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();//used for read (select) operations
```